# R encountered a fatal error! How can I fix it?

Tags: r, macos, rstudio

My RStudio says "R encountered a fatal error.: Unexpected exception: basic_string

The session was terminated".

I checked major information sources like stackoverflow, reddit,R community, but I'm still unable to figure this out. Thank you so much your time in advance!

MacOS: 13.1
R Studio: Version 2022.12.0+353 (2022.12.0+353)Version 2022.12.0+353 (2022.12.0+353)

Error messages R shows
"R encountered a fatal error.: Unexpected exception: basic_string

The session was terminated"
"

R encountered a fatal error.

The session was terminated."
"null"

I uninstalled R and RStudio multiple times and reinstalled again but they all showed the same error messages.

Also, I installed an older version of RStudio but it didn't work either.

This is the hardest challenge that I've ever faced in my data journey.

```
R version 4.2.2 (2022-10-31) -- "Innocent and Trusting"
Copyright (C) 2022 The R Foundation for Statistical Computing
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin17.0 (64-bit)

R is free software and comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY.
You are welcome to redistribute it under certain conditions.
Type 'license()' or 'licence()' for distribution details.

Natural language support but running in an English locale

R is a collaborative project with many contributors.
Type 'contributors()' for more information and
'citation()' on how to cite R or R packages in publications.

Type 'demo()' for some demos, 'help()' for on-line help, or
'help.start()' for an HTML browser interface to help.
Type 'q()' to quit R.

[Previously saved workspace restored]

> sessionInfo()
R version 4.2.2 (2022-10-31)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin17.0 (64-bit)
Running under: macOS Big Sur ... 10.16

Matrix products: default
BLAS:           /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.2/Resources/lib/libRblas.0.dylib  
LAPACK:/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.2/Resources/lib/libRlapack.dylib
locale:
[1] en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/C/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] compiler_4.2.2
```

Comment: Are you running a specific code that encounter this issue? If yes, then try running a simple code that you know that the code is correct. for example:
 z<-c(1:5);plot(z)
If this code works without any issue, then the issue is likely specific to your code. Thats what I can tell

Comment: Hi! Thank you for your response! Once you open the RStudio application, it says it encountered a fatal error!

Comment: I’m asking my classmates, R community, twitter world about this! Really hope I can fix this bug!

Comment: Have you tried reinstalling R? What happens if you try to open R outside of Rstudio?

Comment: Nothing happens. Is there anything I can type R f D directly to fix the problem?

Comment: Can you open a terminal and type `R` (which opens R w/o RStudio), then type `sessionInfo()` and paste the output as edit to your question.

Comment: Hi  jay.sf, I found a way to add codes on my original question so I updated it. Hope this helps you to check what is wrong with my R... thank you a lot!

Comment: @RyoTanaka Well done! Let's see...

Comment: As we can see R works perfectly and the culprit is RStudio. You said you uninstalled RStudio. However, did you also purge when uninstalling? Means: remove all files associated to RStudio. On Linux Ubuntu for instance we can do `apt purge rstudio` (as opposed to just `apt remove rstudio`) which also removes config files which are probably corrupted. You can try sth like that, but as Linux user I'm not sure how it's done on a Mac. However you can try to install an [RStudio daily](https://dailies.rstudio.com/)...

Comment: ...or [reset RStudio's Desktop state:](https://support.posit.co/hc/en-us/articles/200534577-Resetting-RStudio-Desktop-s-State). In the meantime, you can use R on the terminal, as you have just learned :)

Comment: Hi, thank you so much again for taking the time for this. I deleted the files and application once again. I'll reinstall it and see what happens..

Comment: I deleted all the files in the working directory from my computer to reinstall R and RStduio.

Comment: Thanks very much everyone answering my question. So I said goodbye to my RStudio and hello to RStudio Cloud! I'm no longer using the desktop app. I'll check back when I have more time to figure out this endless debugging!

Answer (score 0):

Please remove the .Rdata file from your local directory. Next, uninstall the existing version of RStudio IDE. Lastly, install the most recent version of the IDE

Comment: Everything that everyone said didn't work but one solution... 
I created another user on my Macbook and opened the R there, vola! It worked! Thanks everyone!